# participial construction: heading to Germany

Tags: participle-clauses

Can the following sentence be naturally rewritten as one containing a participial construction?

> a. Those refugees were driven out of their country **and headed** / **and were heading** to Germany.

> b. Those refugees were driven out of their country, **heading** to Germany.

Comment: I think version (b) is clumsy. You might encounter that kind of construction in a "poetic" context, but to my mind it's at the very least "awkward" to discard EITHER the conjunction ***and*** OR the auxiliary verb ***were*** here. To discard *BOTH* of them is definitely not good!

Comment: I'm looking for conditions on what constitutes a good participial clause. This one seems OK: John walked out of his room, slamming the door behind him (= and slammed the door behind him).

Comment: But what makes the participial construction OK in one case but not in the other?

Comment: Exactly what I said. Half of the reason (b) is awkward is becauseyou discarded the conjunction ***and***. The *other* half of the reason is because you discarded the auxiliary ***were***. I'm advising you to forget *both* of these "syntactic devices", I'm sure you know enough about English syntax to be aware that there's no *fundamental* syntactic rule being broken by (b). But it's just not idiomatic, so you should forget it. This isn't a matter of you learning some "deep" idea about grammar - it's just a matter of certain forms becoming idiomatically established, whereas others aren't.

Comment: ...There's also a little bit of clumsiness about juxtaposing ***were driven out** [of X]* (involuntary; something was done ***to*** them) and ***were heading** [for Y]* (voluntary; they chose the destination). But I wouldn't overstate that - it's just a fine point of "style advice".

Comment: How about this?  Those refugees left their country, heading to Germany.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Is there a point to your line of questioning here?

Comment: @Apollyon Both construction are okay (in my understanding), but you may consider changing the word/phrase order. It is because in your example, you cannot bring the participial phrase at the beginning, like "Heading to Germany, those refugees were driven out of their country". But you could do that if the sentence had been, "Driven out of their country, those refugees headed to Germany."